# Finding Index in string with recurring chars

Tags: python, string

I have string `a='51545'`

I am finding index of the each char in the string  like this

```
modchar=[{i:a.index(i)} for i in a ]

#modchar=[{'5': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'5': 0}, {'4': 3}, {'5': 0}]
```

but i need to get it as

```
#modchar=[{'5': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'5': 2}, {'4': 3}, {'5': 4}]
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: It should be `[{'5': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'5': 2}, {'4': 3}, {'5': 4}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a='51545'
obj = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    obj.append({a[i]: i})
```

This runs as:

```
>>> a='51545'
>>> obj = []
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...     obj.append({a[i]: i})
... 
>>> obj
[{'5': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'5': 2}, {'4': 3}, {'5': 4}]
>>>
```

You can do list comprehension using [`enumerate:`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
[{value: index} for value, index in enumerate(a)]
```

Which runs as:

```
>>> [{value: index} for index, value in enumerate(a)]
[{'5': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'5': 2}, {'4': 3}, {'5': 4}]
>>>
```

Or, you can use a basic list comprehension:

```
[{a[index]: index} for index in range(len(a))]
```

Which runs as:

```
>>> [{a[index]: index} for index in range(len(a))]
[{'5': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'5': 2}, {'4': 3}, {'5': 4}]
>>>
```

`enumerate` is basically a combination of using a `for` loop to get the index, and then accessing the list:

```
>>> arr = [5, 8, 2, 4]
>>> for index, value in enumerate(arr):
...     print index, value
... 
0 5
1 8
2 2
3 4
>>>
```

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick: You can also use enumerate in your for loop too. It is generally considered better practice to use enumerate than `range(len(a))`

Comment: @user667648 it's there :)

Comment: It is in your list comprehension, but the for loop can be rewritten as: `for i, _ in enumerate(a):`

Answer (score 10):

In this case, you probably want to [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the string creating the dictionaries as you go:

```
[{c: i} for i, c in enumerate(a)]
```

Note that as a side bonus, this happens in O(n) time opposed to your original solution which is O(n^2)